# Наложение двух background-image

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, background

Добрый день. 
Возник вопрос при верстке макета.
Есть два div с разным background. В макете одна из секций "наезжает" на другую (картинка во вложении). Вопрос в том, как мне их наложить друг на друга? Что бы "уголок" верхнего наехал на нижний background? Спасибо
[image: maket]

```
.about {
  height: 392px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff url("../img/about_bg.png") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  text-align: center;
.benefits {
  height: 554px;
  background: #0099cc url("../img/benefits_bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

Я пробовал делать это с помощью z-index, но нижний фон обрезался на "острие" верхнего.

Comment: Можно через отрицательный `margin-top` для нижнего слоя попробовать или нижнему слою задать `position: relative; top: -20px;` и `z-index` прописать для слоев не забудь.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и делал. Но, получается, что треугольник у верхнего слоя тоже исчезает... А нужно, что бы он остался.

Comment: Приведите ссылку или код на то, что есть.

Comment: [link](http://i.piccy.info/i9/3cacd86103e1a6b20ad48f09fdda1c73/1473180386/171877/1067594/Untitled_1.jpg) ссылка на то, что получается. А код CSS есть в тексте вопроса. Или какой-то другой код нужен? Спасибо

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5aa8bk99/ или использовать изображение уголок

Comment: у вас у верхнего слоя z-index должен быть больше чем у нижнего. Если дадите полную ссылку на изображения напишу пример.

Comment: Уголок можно сделать и через псевдоелементы `:before` ил `:after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с псевдоелементом:

```css
.about {
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../img/about_bg.png") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.about:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 20px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  -left: 50%;
}

.benefits {
  height: 44px;
  background: #0099cc url("../img/benefits_bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about"></div>
<div class="benefits"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Задачу на 100% не решилась, но я понял, как обыграть все это.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с использованием `z-index`:

```css
.about {
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../img/about_bg.png") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.benefits {
  height: 24px;
  background: #0099cc url("../img/benefits_bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 19;
}
```

```html
<div class="about"></div>
<div class="benefits"></div>
```